# Jersey 2 ApplicationEventListener onEvent() not called

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

The `ApplicationEventListener#onEvent` is never called. What could be wrong here.The resource config class is used and i am able to call APIs.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.MyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

App configuration:

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig{
    @NameBinding
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface Secured {}

    public MyApplication(){

        register(com.UserLogin.class);

        register(com.MyApplicationEventListener.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks fine. You can see a test in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/psamsotha/d5de14c76eed39e4585444f6e9d8648b)

Comment: @peeskillet am doing the exact same thing. I am expecting the Sysout statements will be printed on EclipseIDE console when i am starting /stopping the tomcat server.but there are none.Anything i can debug at my end?

Comment: Unless you make a request, Jersey will not be fully started, so the listener will never be called by just starting and stopping the server. You need to set `<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>` in the web.xml for the servlet configuration. This will cause Jersey to fully load when the server starts

Comment: Got it. load-on-startup is what i actually want. Thanks so much for your prompt help.

Comment: @peeskillet can you please point me to some good tutorial where i can get to know how to load and setup app.properties at application start ,to be reusable across the resources and helper classes. I want the properties file to be available as a bundle instead of adding each property singly to the context.

Comment: https://psamsotha.github.io/jersey/2015/12/27/jersey-configuration-properties.html

Comment: @peeskillet i got it all working.Thx. i am having trouble in injecting a ApplicationLevel Service (initialized in ApplicationEventListener) ,so that it is available across my resources and helper classes.

Comment: I have posted answer so you can close this post. If you have unlrelated questions, please post another question. Comments are really not suitable for this type of discussion (help)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you make a request, Jersey will not be fully started, so the listener will never be called by just starting and stopping the server. You need to set `<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>` in the web.xml for the servlet configuration. This will cause Jersey to fully load when the server starts.